# Enabling RSpec work work with Rubymine and Rails dynamic finder methods missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rubymine, nomethoderror

I'm trying to run a simple RSpec test inside of RubyMine on top of a rails application. I'm trying to test some generic code inside of a lib directory. The problem is that I get an exception NoMethodError. I can run the same code from "rails console" without any issue.

NoMethodError: undefined method `find_or_initialize_by_content_service_id' for #<Class:0x000000048f8f28>
/home/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:984:in`method_missing'

So what is needed in RubyMine so that the rails dynamic methods work?

I'm using Rails 3, RubyMine 3.2.4, RSpec 2.
Thanks.